gradle-based IntelliJ project: How do set to Java21+?
This Java switch statement doesn't work on with my IntelliJ settings. Can someone help me point to the right portions of IntelliJ where I can solve this problem?
Intelij displays error message:
error: illegal start of expression return switch (setType) {

when running this code:
private static SimpleAbstractSet<String> makeSet(String setType){
    return switch (setType) {
        case "HashSet" -> new SimpleHashSet<>();
        case "TreeSet" -> new SimpleTreeSet<>();
        ...
        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    };
}

The code I'm using is from the MOOC "Functional Programming with Java and Threads from the vanderBiltUniveristy. It is on https://github.com/douglascraigschmidt/ and does work with them. Therefore I'm looking in my environment and IDE setup to see if I can find the error.
Linux CentOS

java version 21.0.4
gradle version 8.4
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-21.0.4-oracle-x64
GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-8.4
PATH=/opt/gradle/gradle-8.4/bin:/usr/lib/jvm-21.0.4-oracle-x64/bin:.....

InteliJ Project Structure

SDK: 21 Oracle OpenJDK 21.0.4
Language level 21- Record patterns,.....
JDK home path /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-21.0.4-oracle-x64

InteliJ Project Settings

Gradle user home /opt/gradle/gradle-8.4
Gradle JVM JAVA_HOME

gradle-wrapper.properties

...
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip
...

build gradle
group 'livelessons'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.14.3'
}

Solution
InteliJ Setting | Build Tools | Gradle
every example of the MOOC is a separate gradle project. For reasons I do not know some of the projects are set by inteliJ to use Gradle JVM 11. These need to be set to JAVA_HOME Oracle OpenJDK 21.0.4

Works on my machine (java 21.0.2). Double check the line before the return and make sure you're looking at the correct file (e.g., you have saved the file)

Did you add a default case?

@Computable that would give a different error ("the switch expression does not cover all possible input values")

@DanielBlack That's legal, no problem. You might be confused due to 'switch as an expression' being rather new to java.

Not reproducible - this works fine for me. Likely culprit: You claim lang level is at 21, but that's not actually happening. Whatever is producing that error is interpreting your java source file based on JDK at a version less than 21. Check your settings, check that gradle file, and so forth. Stop looking at the java source file - the problem will not be found there. (switch as expression is quite new, hence, the problem is, something is targeted at an older java version where switch as expression isn't supported).

Switch expression where introduced as final feature in Java 14 which was released on March 17, 2020. Maybe your build file specifies an older version (like Java 11)

@rzwitserloot that's pretty cool, thanks for letting me know!

Show your build.gradle.

@MarkRotteveel I have added the build.gradle. Not sure how this helps. I'm afraid it is an issue in InteliJ.

@rzwitserloot It is not an issue in the java coe. That is from the MOOC and not changed. You can find it on the github page. I'm afraid it is an issue in InteliJ. I have posted al settings that I know. The settings that I do not know about might be wrong. I need someone to point me to the InteliJ setting that causes this error.

@Computable The Java file comes from the MOOC. Yes the did put in a default case. For completeness I have added it to the question. I'm afraid it is not an issue in the Java code but in the settings of InteliJ. Besides the ones I have set and are mentioned in the question I do not know where else to look in InteliJ.

@FedericoklezCulloca Thank you for checking. I'm glad to hear, but not surprised, that it works on your machine. Can you help me identify the settings in InteliJ that makes this work?

@Edwin sorry, I'm not familiar with intellij, I only checked the code. FWIW I added the intelli-j tag and voted to reopen your question. Hope you find a solution.

@Edwin You must be confused. I am telling you it is not an issue in the java code and you respond with 'it is not an issue in the java code'. Uh, yes. Exactly. We all are trying to tell you that. Now that your gradle build file is included, perhaps someone can help - it does not state 'version 21 please' which seems like an issue. Let's re-open.

Solution
InteliJ Setting | Build Tools | Gradle
Every example of the MOOC is a separate gradle project. For reasons I do not know some of the projects are set by inteliJ to use Gradle JVM 11. These need to be set to JAVA_HOME Oracle OpenJDK 21.0.4
